# Logback not working with Prudent Mode is true

Tags: java, logback

we are using below log file for logging data but we are not able to create file named as "mylogfile.log" which contains current date Logs .
however its creating Log file named as  Logs "mylogfile2015.02.05.log for current day also as its not refering the  tag defined.

Need help to create log file(mylogfile.log) without Date with Prudent mode is true to support multiple JVM's.

```
<appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${MY_LOG_LOCATION_PROP}/logs/mylogfile.log</file>
        <prudent>true</prudent>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <!-- rollover daily -->
            <fileNamePattern>mylogfile-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log</fileNamePattern>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess you can't set *file* property of *RollingFileAppender* while using **prudent mode**.

Check [this](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#prudentWithRolling).